# "Par for the course"

Tags: phrases, popular-refrains, colloquialisms

From your personal experience, is "par for the course" widely understood, or would you recommend using a less technical term?

I am particularly interested in differences between American, British, and Australian English.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that "par for the course" is a technical term; I would call technical term an expression like "par for the exhange".

Comment: In what context do you want to use the phrase? The question is just  impossible to answer without any context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Golf is played worldwide, so I would expect that the phrase -- even if not idiomatic in the local dialect -- would be readily understood by most.

However, I can only speak with certainty for the U.S., where this is definitely a common expression.

Comment: I learned the meaning of par only when I played Wii golf :)

Comment: @Bruno - I don't think everyone necessarily understands what the word "par" is but they should still understand the idiom "par for the course".

Answer (score 3):

Even people who don't understand that the idiom originated in Golf have heard the phrase frequently and understand its meaning. As children learning our native language, we learn idioms long before we learn their source. Many people never do learn (or care about) the source of the phases they use daily.

In fact, I'd say that's par for the course. If you don't understand that, I suppose I could take another tack.

Comment: For example, "take another tack" is a sailing term yet people understand it readily.

Comment: @mmyers - I once worked with a clue-less landlubber who insisted on saying "take another tact", and who would not be corrected, not matter how tactful a tack I took.

Comment: @mickeyf - that's part of the course

Comment: Just a small correction (I popped here to check for a potential duplicate) - this expression doesn't originate from golf, it is a loanword from Latin that the usage in the English language predates the golf by 3 centuries. Par means "equal" (so in most of the Latin languages, and also Dutch, is used to symbolize two equal things, a pair).

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza "Par" or course means equal, or in the case of golf more or less "the expected average". But "for the course" I believe nails the complete phrase down to Golf as the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Since the words "sub-par" and "on par" are fairly common, I think people could figure out what "par for the course" means.

Comment: Since it's a golf term, shouldn't "sub-par" be good?

Comment: It certainly should be! But it isn't. :)

Comment: That's because the expression doesn't originate from golf, it originates from Latin. "Subpar" means "Less than equal", so it is bad.